# Python - Beautiful Soup - Class name exists twice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm just learning how to use BS4 right now but 1 thing I haven't really figured out is how to go about getting a span class that's within another span class with the same name.

HTML Example

```
<span class="test class">
 <span class="another class">
  <span class="test class">
        data I want
  </span>
```

What I have been doing for other pieces of data is something like

```
find('span', class_="test class").get_text().strip()
```

but this takes the first class when I want to take the 2nd.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enforce the search inside the element with `another class` class. You can do it by chaining the `find()` calls:

```
elm = soup.find('span', class_="another class").find('span', class_="test class")
print(elm.get_text())
```

Or, in one go using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
elm = soup.select_one("span.another.class > span.test.class")
print(elm.get_text())
```

where `>` means a direct parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_all('span', class_="test class")[1].get_text().strip()
```

This will find all instances of the span with class = 'test class', store that in a list. Then we select the second element of the list, which will correspond to the second ocurrence of the test class.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<span class="test class">
 <span class="another class">
  <span class="test class">
        data I want
  </span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find('span', class_="test class")
print span.get_text().strip()
>>> data I want
```

System details:

- Python 2.7.6
- beautifulsoup4==4.4.0

Comment: But what if 
html = """
<span class="test class">
   data I don't want
 <span class="another class">
  <span class="test class">
        data I want
  </span>
"""